Symmetrized versions of Laguerre polynomials

It is well known that the Laguerre polynomials are complete in the Hilbert space $L^2$ with inner product
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) g(x) dx
$$
In general, these polynomials are neither even nor odd with respect to the origin.
For a research problem I am working on, I consider the
space $X$ of square integrable functions $f$ such that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty\
\mbox{with inner product}\
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} f(x)g(x)dx
$$
One can easily see that if $f$ is even and $g$ is odd, then $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal.
Moreover, since any function $f$ can be uniquely written as the sum of an even function and an odd function via
$$
f(x)=1/2 [(f(x)+f(-x))+(f(x)-f(-x))],
$$
we have an orthogonal decomposition $X=P\oplus Q$ where $P$ consists of odd functions and $Q$ consists of even functions in the Hilbert space $X$.
One can then use Gram-Schmidt to convert the set
$\{x,x^3,x^5,\ldots\}$ in $P$ and
the set $\{1,x^2,x^4,\ldots\}$ in $Q$ into orthogonal odd polynomials $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}\subset P$ and orthogonal even polynomials $\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}\subset Q$.

My question is the following:
Are $\{p_1,p_2\,\ldots\}$ and $\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}$ complete respectively in $P$ and $Q$ ?. Surely this must be known but I can't seem to find this in any of the classic textbooks.
Any reference would be appreciated.

If I remember correctly, the Laguerre polynomials are solutions to a differential equation that lends itself to an eigenvector/eigenvalue approach. The corresponding linear operator commutes with the parity operator, $x \to -x$. This implies the existence of simultaneous eigenfunctions.  Eigenfunctions of the parity operator are necessarily symmetric. So find that differential equation, establish that the operator commutes with the parity operator, and prove the symmetry of eigenfunctions of the parity operator. Should do it.
